# How to set device's twin properties without Etag?

Tags: c#, performance, azure, azure-iot-hub

I am using the API:

```
RegistryManager.UpdateTwinAsync(string deviceId, Twin twinPatch, string etag);
```

However, it need to call device's twin first:

```
Twin twin= await _registryManager.GetTwinAsync(deviceId);
var etag = twin.Etag
```

So I need to 2 I/O call, that decreases application performance.

Is there any way to set device's twin without getting Etag first?

Thanks,

Comment: In the case of device twin at the service-facing side such as tags and desired properties, the REST PATCH can be used, see more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/updatetwin In the case of initialize a device, I do recommend to use registryManager.ImportDevicesAsync job method. Note, that the runtime owner of the device twin reported properties is a device-facing endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DeviceClient`'s `UpdateReportedPropertiesAsync` or, if you want to serialize you data yourself, `SendEventAsync(Message message)`.

`DeviceClient` is in `Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client` library.

Also, you can cache the etag to improve performance (but that depends on how you app works).

Comment: Thank for your information! however, I want to use RegistryManager class to update properties.

Comment: Then you will need to supply the `etag` :)

Comment: have you tried using `*` as an ETag value? just bear in mind that the ETag is there to avoid losing data, so make sure that's what you really want.